# SQL Server 2012 database in suspect mode after upgrade from Developer to Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server-2012

SQL Server database is in suspect mode after an upgrade from developer to standard edition 2012 version. In the log file there are two errors: 933 and error 905. Following error occurred when we tried to get the database back online.

> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 ALTER DATABASE statement failed. Msg 905, Level 21, State 1, Line 1 Database 'VTSDB' cannot be started in this edition of SQL Server because it contains a partition function 'FNprocessedrawdata'. Only Enterprise edition of SQL Server supports partitioning. Msg 933, Level 21, State 1, Line 1 Database 'VTSDB' cannot be started because some of the database functionality is not available in the current edition of SQL Server.

Comment: I hope you made a backup.  As in the excellent answer from Antoine what you have is a license upgrade but actually product downgrade.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server Developer Edition is functionally equal to Enterprise Edition. The error is stating you are using features that only Developer or Enterprise support, such as Table Partitioning in this case. In order to use Standard, you cannot use any Enterprise features.

Check [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc645993(SQL.110).aspx) for more details.

One way to fix this issue would be to take the following steps:

> 1. Take the database offline.
> 2. Install a new named instance temporarily with Developer or Enterprise edition (database engine only as that is all that is needed
>      for this).
> 3. Copy the data and log files from current location to new location.
> 4. On temporary instance, attach database and make sure you point to the copied files in the new location and not the original files. It
>      should have no problems and bring the database up.
> 5. Remove any Enterprise features from the link above. Use the following query to see what is used in that database "**SELECT feature_name FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features**"
> 6. Detach database from temporary location.
> 7. Rename original database files by appending some word (_orig as an example) to the current name.
> 8. Move files from temporary location to same location as original files (assuming these files have same name as original files).
> 9. Attach database to Standard instance by selecting the file you just copied
> 10. Database should come up with no issues at this point.
> 11. Turn off temporary SQL instance.
> 12. After verifying everything is ok, uninstall the temporary instance.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a solution to the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as Paparazzi mentioned, you are actually doing a product downgrade. 
But with everything already in place, I would suggest to download a copy of SQL Server Enterprise (Evaluation version) and try to upgrade the standard version, and if everything is fine, I will make the necessary changes (i.e. remove those enterprise features, such as partitions). After that, I will create a new instance of standard version, and then migrate everything (logins / jobs / databases etc) from the evaluation version to the standard version.

Comment: OP already has developer.  Why create a new instance of Standard?