# ms sql database in suspect mode when we upgrade from developer to standard edition

Tags: sql-server

sql database in suspect mode when we upgrade from developer to standard edition 2012 version.
in log file there is two error occurred `933` and error `905`.
following error occurred when we try to get back online the db

> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>   Msg 905, Level 21, State 1, Line 1 Database 'VTSDB' cannot be started
>   in this edition of SQL Server because it contains a partition function
>   'FNprocessedrawdata'. Only Enterprise edition of SQL Server supports
>   partitioning. Msg 933, Level 21, State 1, Line 1 Database 'VTSDB'
>   cannot be started because some of the database functionality is not
>   available in the current edition of SQL Server.

Comment: Developer to Standard isn't really an upgrade.  Developer and Enterprise are mostly the same product with different licensing.  Standard does not have all the bells and whistles that Developer and Enterprise do.  At least that is my experience in prior versions.  I haven't worked extensively with 2012.  If you need Enterprise functionality then you probably should have upgraded to Enterprise.

Comment: Error message is clear.Developer edition is same as Enterprise edition but with some limitations. when you Bumped Developer edition to Standard,partitioning wont work ,since it is only enterprise only feature..You will need to remove enterprise only features which will be shown by this dmv(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc280724.aspx),i am not sure how you can do it now if your database is in suspect mode.

Comment: Duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/144049/3690